# How do we include the base services of alljoyn in universal web application

Tags: javascript, android, windows-runtime, alljoyn

Iam trying to build a universal web application(producer) which uses my own interface and its build using Alljoyn Studio.

Now i want to add the notification service, to send the notification to the consumer which is a (android)application.

how do i implement the notification service/Control panel  in UWP?

please provide me some suggestions.

Comment: are you meaning Alljoyn notification?

Comment: yes Alljoyn Notification service.

Answer (score 0):

For sending Notification to any android Device you can use two technology: 1) Push. 2) Pull.

For Push Technology you can use GCM(Google cloud messaging).

For Pull Technology you can make you application continuously keep on connecting to server and trying to fetch data if it is available from there.

Advantages of GCM: 
1) Low battery comsumption. Since it will push the message to user device and it will push message when user gets connected to server.

For GCM you can use following Link for your reference:

1. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
2. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en
3. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/implementing-googles-cloud-to-device-messaging/428
4. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html
5. https://github.com/teleknEsis/TechRepublic-Samples/tree/master/C2DMSample

Comment: the question requests for Alljoyn notifications, not GCM